# Is there a way to gently shut down the Visual Studio web server

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side, visual-studio-debugging

I have some code in my Blazor server app that, I believe, runs when IIS shuts down (via IDisposable). Is there a way, when running under the Visual Studio debugger, to have it perform the shutdown notifications/operations that occur when running on Azure App Server and it gently shuts down there?

Comment: I'm not sure how you have your code hooked up, but if I use `app.Lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("Stopping"));` in my `program.cs` and then use Ctrl-C in the console that is running the app, it triggers a shutdown and runs that code.

Comment: @MisterMagoo That's it! If you make that an answer, happy to accept it.

Comment: Looks like we have some people who didn't understand the question and closed it. Typical really.

Comment: @MisterMagoo Yeah - nonsensical closings are annoying.

Comment: @MisterMagoo It's re-opened. If you write the answer I'm happy to select your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
app.Lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("Stopping"));
```

in `program.cs` and then use Ctrl-C in the console that is running the app, it triggers a shutdown and runs that code.